# fixed menu width - items distribution

Tags: html, css, menu, items, fixed-width

I have list menu

```
<ul>
<li>item1</li>
<li>item2</li>
<li>longitem3</li>
</ul>
```

menu css

```
ul{
width:500px;
}
li {
float:left;
}
```

i would like to automatically distribute my items in menu so they would have the same space between them like this

{menu}{item}{space}{item}{space}{item}{menu}

is it possible to do this using only html and css, not javascript? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a css class rather than affecting all the < li>, like this:

```
<li class="menuItem">
```

As for the css:

```
.menuItem {
    float: left;
    margin-right: <some number of px>;
}
.menuItem:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

The ':last-child' selector overrides the previous definition and removes the right space for the last menu item.

Comment: ok thanks. the thing I'm trying to solve is if I have to calculate margin od padding by myself or I can set it up somehow to do it automatically. To avoid recalculating of margins/paddings when menu li item is added

Comment: Without javascript I'm not seeing any elegant solution. There are a couple of hacks that you can use though. If you will have a maximum number of elements, try this: http://leaverou.me/2011/01/styling-children-based-on-their-number-with-css3/ and if your page is only going to be used in IE you can use css expressions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537634(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can add a margin to the right side of your li's

```
li { float:left; margin-right: 5px}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add some padding to the right of each `li` item, e.g.

```
li {
float:left;
padding-right:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ul {
    text-align: center;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```